# Can a service-worker communicate with clients during 'install' event handler?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm building a PWA that is primary for offline use so I'm caching everything during the install process:

```js
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
  self.skipWaiting();
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(everything);
    })
  );
});
```

Is there any way during this step to communicate the progress of the caching to the client?

It doesn't look like the `event` in the "install" listener has a `clientId` to `postMessage`s to.

Do `new BroadcastChannel()`s work in service workers?

I don't need a precise bytes progress/loaded, maybe just a files completed. Could I replace `client.addAll` with something like this?

```js
for(let file of everything) {
  await cache.add(file);
  /* ...message clients another file is cached */
}
```